# How to specify Prometheus output format while querying?

Tags: prometheus, influxdb, opentsdb

When I [query](http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=%7Bjob%3D~%22..%2A%22%7D) Prometheus, I am getting `JSON` in response, is it possible to specify the output format in the query for example in the output I am looking for `opentsdb` or `influx` format.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [remote-storage](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/) and using either `remoteWrite` or `remoteRead`, [specs](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/api.md#prometheusspec)

The architecture is as follows:
[image]